# Deploy to multiple environments with Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following build step in my github actions file which deploys my code to my production environment;

```
build:
  name: Deploy to production
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: tests
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
  steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup PHP
      uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
      with:
        php-version: 8.1
        extensions: dom, curl, libxml, mbstring, zip, pcntl, pdo, sqlite, pdo_sqlite
        coverage: none

    - name: Deploy
      uses: deployphp/action@master
      with:
        dep: deploy production -f ./build/deployer/deploy.php
        private-key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
        known-hosts: ${{ secrets.KNOWN_HOSTS }}
        deployer-version: "7.1.4"
```

This deploys only on the `main` branch. What i would like to do is duplicate this for a development environment, which only deploys on the `develop` branch and uses the following variables for the deploy step;

```
dep: deploy dev -f ./build/deployer/deploy.php
private-key: ${{ secrets.DEV_PRIVATE_KEY }}
known-hosts: ${{ secrets.DEV_KNOWN_HOSTS }}
```

Im very new to github actions, is it possible to do this? this way pushing to develop branch will deploy to a dev environment and pushing to main branch will push to production

Comment: You can configure secrets for all your environment with the same name and they'll automatically be switched according to your `environment` configuration.